# How to find the number of bytes allocated by malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following code:

```
    int size = 0;
void* ptr; 

ptr = malloc(9); //we want to allocate 9 bytes

size = sizeof(*ptr); 
printf("size = %d\n", size);
```

This results in size equal to `1`. Is there a way for size to be `9`??

Comment: There is no portable way to find that out.

Comment: I was asked a while back by a pretty big company during an interview 1) how do you allocate memory for X bytes. 2) suppose all you have is a pointer to allocated memory, How do you find out how much space was allocated? was it a trick question then?

Comment: I am not sure, it is possible.

Comment: `was it a trick question?` Yes and no. Some `malloc` implementations store a memory control block ahead of the memory address returned to the program. So theoretically you could look there to find the size of the allocated block. So if you discussed the details of the memory control block on every system that you've ever used, they would have been very impressed. But simply stating that the program itself has to keep track of such information would have been the correct answer.  In other words, the question was an opportunity for you to display your depth of knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way for size to be 9??

There is no portable way to find that out.

But if you are using GNU system (Glibc), you could use `malloc_usable_size(3)`.

Note: the size returned by `malloc_usable_size` could be larger than the size given to corresponding `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to remember the size of the memory allocated by malloc, you should store it somewhere else.

You could also use an array, then `sizeof` would gives you an appropriate result... But it wouldn't work anyway if you use a `void *` type.